# Serving HTTP/1.0 responses with Node.JS (unknown content length, chunked transfer encoding)

Tags: http, node.js, http-1.1, transfer-encoding, http-1.0

### The Problem

I am serving a resource of unknown length via Node.JS.  Because of this, the `Content-Length` header cannot be set.  For HTTP 1.1, it is required that chunked encoding is used for resources of this nature.  Node.JS knows this and sends my data with chunked transfer encoding all on its own, with the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
...
```

This is all fine and good for well-behaved clients.  **However, I have some not-so-well behaved clients (namely Android 2.2 and earlier) that I must support.**  These clients do not support chunked transfer encoding properly.

### Fix Attempt #1

My initial thought was set the encoding to `none` like so:

```
response.writeHead(200, {'Transfer-Encoding': 'none'});
```

This disables Node.JS's automatic chunked encoding and maintains compatibility with *most* clients.  However, now I have broken Android 2.3+ clients, as they simply cough and choke when they see such a bogus transfer encoding header.

### Fix Attempt #2 (where I need help)

When I make requests with `HTTP/1.0`, the server properly returns the response without chunked encoding:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
...
```

This solves my problem, and allows me to serve a stream that works for all of my troublesome clients.  I don't have to send a bogus header for `Transfer-Encoding`, and I still don't have to specify how long the content is.

**How can I force Node.JS's HTTP server to always serve in HTTP/1.0 mode?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Forcing non-chunked responses, the right way

There's a supported way of turning off chunked encoding: you simply need to remove the `Transfer-Encoding` header using [request.removeHeader(name)](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_removeheader_name):

```
response.removeHeader('transfer-encoding');
```

Node.js will respect no matter what. There's even a [test](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v8.6.0/test/parallel/test-http-remove-header-stays-removed.js#L32) to prevent someone from accidentally changing this behavior, so I think it's pretty safe to use.

So you can just stick with attempt #1, but doing it as described above.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad to see this was added.  I'll give it a try, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

For my purposes, I found an easy way to disable the forced usage of chunked, using an undocumented property of the response object:

```
response.useChunkedEncodingByDefault = false;
```

It's that simple.  Of course, relying on this property to be available for future versions of Node.js isn't the best.  Perhaps there is a better solution, but this works for me for now.

Comment: @JamundFerguson, Not that I've seen.  Is this solution not working for you?

Comment: So we're seeing this issue when code is serviced through a CDN down to NGINX into our node server. In those cases we're seeing "cannot decode raw data" errors in our mobile browsers. It's sort-of reproducible (for us) by doing `curl -H "TE: chunked;q=1.0" -k --compressed http://nginx/`, but anyway. Our NGINX version is older and it seems updating it solves the problem for us.

Comment: @JamundFerguson, Hmmm, somewhere along the line a header is probably getting mangled.  Also, do you have `Vary: Transfer-Encoding, Accept` set in your response headers?  (Doesn't matter a lot for non-cacheable resources.)  I would suggest posting a new question, and send me a link.

Comment: Here's the line preventing a good fix in Node.js:  https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js#L221  the HTTP status line is hard-coded to HTTP/1.1.  The only way around this is to interface with the socket directly.

Answer (score 1):

`Transfer-Encoding: identity` should also work.